# powershell wait-job doesn't wait

Tags: powershell, process, wait, jobs, suspend

I'm trying to get a set instructions to wait until a process is finished before they start but I keep having the variables try to run straight after.

I would try a `wait()` but I cant know how long the scan will take.

```
#Variables
$logPath = "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\log.txt"
$scanPath = "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\scan.txt"
$repairLog = "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\repair.txt"
$failLog = "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\fail.txt"
$computer = "SERVER2012"
$CBSFileLocation = "C:\Windows\Logs\CBS\CBS.log"
$date = Get-Date
$sevenDays = New-Object System.TimeSpan 7,0,0,0,0
$repair = "Repair"
$fail = "fail"
$then = $date.Subtract($sevenDays)

#Start of Code:
$EventLog = Get-EventLog -LogName System -ComputerName $computer -After $then -Before $date -EntryType Error | Out-File $logPath
Start-Job -Name SFC {Start-Process sfc /scannow}

#I want the wait/suspend here.
Wait-Job -Name SFC {
    $ScanX = Get-Content $CBSFileLocation
    $ScanX | Out-File $scanPath
    Select-String -Path $scanPath -Pattern $repair | Out-File $repairLog
    Select-String -Path $scanPath -Pattern $fail | Out-File $failLog
    echo "Done!!"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you want to wait, and when SFC is ready, execute the script inside the last `{ ... }` in your scripts.

As far as I can tell from reading the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/wait-job) for `Wait-Job`, there is no scriptblock parameter what would allow for this.

Instead try rearranging your code a little, like this

```
#Variables
$logPath = "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\log.txt"
$scanPath = "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\scan.txt"
$repairLog = "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\repair.txt"
$failLog = "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\fail.txt"
$computer = "SERVER2012"
$CBSFileLocation = "C:\Windows\Logs\CBS\CBS.log"
$date = Get-Date
$sevenDays = New-Object System.TimeSpan 7,0,0,0,0
$repair = "Repair"
$fail = "fail"
$then = $date.Subtract($sevenDays)

#Start of Code:
$EventLog = Get-EventLog -LogName System -ComputerName $computer -After $then -Before $date -EntryType Error | Out-File $logPath

#Start the job and return the prompt once the job has State Completed
Start-Job {Start-Process sfc /scannow} | Wait-Job

#These lines are executed once Wait-Job above returns the prompt
$ScanX = Get-Content $CBSFileLocation
$ScanX | Out-File $scanPath
Select-String -Path $scanPath -Pattern $repair | Out-File $repairLog
Select-String -Path $scanPath -Pattern $fail | Out-File $failLog
echo "Done!!"
```

Comment: I just deleted a similar answer, because yours was faster and better.